# MongoDB dynamic result

Tags: mongodb

In SQL it is possible to add fields which are not in the table model and to render them during the query. Is MongoDB able to do the same in the model and / or in the query ?

For instance, is there "a way" to store a document in the example collection:

```
db.example.save(
{
"name":"randomValue",
"random": function(){ return Math.random() };
})
```

Where `find.example.find();` Would result in an "evaluated" document result like:

```
{"name":"randomValue", "random":0.9879878, "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ef1d1…" }}
```

(the function being evaluated would be replaced by its returned value)

If this is only feasible in specifying the function in the query, how to do so ?

Comment: You need a random value *each* time you invoke find(), or it's just an example to illustrate your question?

Comment: It's an example, it is quite easy to set a value on save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current way to dynamically evaluate or mix-in values to a recordset.

As you say you can store functions but you have to evaluate them by iterating through each document and calling doc.random = `db.eval('doc.random')` that would replace the original function with a value - which probably isn't what you want.

You can also store functions in `db.system.js` and call them to return a modified dataset - running db.eval does have some draw backs, map reduce may be a better fit.

Check out: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is: no, it is not possible.

Such functionality is a part of '*presentation*' layer. When you displaying data on ui you usually prepare ui model. During this step you can call any function and extend your model from client language.

Or if you need to have some extra value (that should be evaluated by some function) in the document  you can call this function before save document. For example, shell script that save random value evaluated by `Math.Random` in `random` field:

```
random = Math.random();
db.example.save(
{
  "name":"randomValue",
  "random": random
})
```

Hope this helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at MongoDB.Dynamic:

http://mongodbdynamic.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: It's nice to see that things are evolving. PS: I would advise to put some usage example on the site.